# Comparing Request Parameters in JSP

Tags: jsp, exception, compare

I'm having a servlet in which i want to compare the request parameters. I'm using following code

```
  <body>
    <%
        if(request.getParameter("type")!=null)
               {
            if(request.getParameter("type").equals("recover"))
                                   {
    %>
                <h1>Recover</h1>
    <%
               }
                           }
                   else if(request.getParameter("type")!=null)
                           {
                       if(request.getParameter("type").equals("reset"))
                                                         {
    %>
    <h1>Reset</h1>
    <%
           }
                                                 }
        %>
</body>
```

but this jsp gives a compile time exception stacktrace follows

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /recover.jsp at line 16

 </head>
<body>
     <%
         if(request.getParameter("type").equals("recover")) <--- line16
               {
    %>
     <h1>Recover</h1>
```

I don't know whats going wrong because this is the correct way to compare strings.

Comment: That works fine in my jsp, is there anything else in the full stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the JSTL instead:

```
<c:if test="${param.type == 'recover'}">
    <h1>Recover</h1>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${param.type == 'reset'}">
    <h1>Reset</h1>
</c:if>
```

You wouldn't have to care about the parameter being null, and it would be much cleaner. scriptlets should not be used anymore. And that's true for a loooong time.

Answer (score 0):

`request.getParameter()` can return null, you may want to check and make sure that the return value is not-null before doing `.equals()`.